# How can you use the iOS camera in AS3?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, camera

Can you use the camera of an iOS device in an AS3 app? If so, how?

Comment: You _do_ know that you can't run Flash (and therefore no AS3) on iOS, don't you?

Comment: now you can flash has develloped in the CS5 the capabilitites to compile it into ipa files... as i was not finding an Xcode Version for windows i choosed to devellop it on flash @0xJoKe

Comment: @0xJoKe You *do* know that [you *can* run Flash on iOS](https://github.com/comex/frash), don't you?

Comment: @H2CO3 Does this work for iOS6?

Comment: Then I apologize for my presumptuous comment @H2CO3

Comment: By the way, you can use the camera the same way you do it on the web, of which there are many examples for - reading this on a tablet otherwise I'd help more with some links :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep it's really easy, there are many ways to access the camera in AS3.

Firstly, the same way as you access the camera in normal AS3 applications:

```
var camera:Camera = Camera.getCamera();
var video=new Video();
video.attachCamera(camera);
this.addChild(video);
```

This will display the camera in the current display object.

You can also ask for images from the Camera roll using the CameraRoll class:

```
import flash.media.CameraRoll;
var cameraRoll:CameraRoll = new CameraRoll();

if(CameraRoll.supportsBrowseForImage) 
{
    cameraRoll.addEventListener(MediaEvent.SELECT, imageSelected); 
    cameraRoll.addEventListener(Event.CANCEL, browseCancelled); 
    cameraRoll.addEventListener(ErrorEvent.ERROR, mediaError); 

    // Ask the user to select an image
    cameraRoll.browseForImage(); 
}
```

You can use the native "camera" application to take a photo:

```
import flash.media.CameraUI;

var cameraUI:CameraUI = new CameraUI();

if (CameraUI.isSupported ) 
{
    cameraUI.addEventListener(MediaEvent.COMPLETE, imageSelected); 
    cameraUI.addEventListener(Event.CANCEL, browseCancelled); 
    cameraUI.addEventListener(ErrorEvent.ERROR, mediaError); 

    cameraUI.launch(MediaType.IMAGE); 
}
```

Hope that points you in the right direction.

Comment: and how do I use thew image back @Micheal

Comment: @NicolasSleiman Which method did you use? Generally you get a BitmapData structure and can use that, but the details depend on which method you went with.